# Play! 2.4 add complementary configuration file

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework-2.4

I recently updated Play framework to 2.4 and I've got a problem with my configuration management.

Previously, I was using a primary `application.conf` file and specific configuration files `application.dev.conf` and `application.prod.conf` to override some configuration values.

With the new version, however, it seems that the configuration is not correctly merged. I use the following ApplicationLoader as showed in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader):

```
package config

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import play.api.{Logger, ApplicationLoader, Configuration}
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.inject.guice._

class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
  override def builder(context : ApplicationLoader.Context) = {
    val mode = context.environment.mode.toString
    val extraConfName = s"application.${mode.toLowerCase}.conf")
    val extra = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(extraConfName))
    initialBuilder
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(extra ++ context.initialConfiguration)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }
}
```

And I added this class loader in my `application.conf` file:

```
play.application.loader = "config.CustomApplicationLoader"
```

But only the values from `application.conf` seems to be taken into account in the final configuration. Any idea of where this could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was using the wrong method from [ConfigFactory](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html), using the method `parseResource` will retrieve only the additionnal keys instead of putting them in a default configuration like `load` is doing.

So the following code will work as expected:

```
class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
  override def builder(context : ApplicationLoader.Context) = {
    val mode = context.environment.mode.toString
    val extraConfName = s"application.${mode.toLowerCase}.conf"
    val extra = Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseResources(extraConfName))
    initialBuilder
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration ++ extra)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }
}
```